# Automapper - Map fail from class to list

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I got the following mapping :

- Class A to List
- Class B to class C

So, here is the snippet:

```
// Mapping from class A to IEnumerable<B>
cfg.CreateMap<A, IEnumerable<B>>().ConvertUsing((i, o) => i.listB);
// Mapping from class B to class C
cfg.CreateMap<B, C>();

var listB = mapper.Map<A, IEnumerable<B>>(instanceA); // Works
var instanceC = mapper.Map<B, C>(listB.First()); // Works
var listC = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<B>, IEnumerable<C>>(listB); // Works

var listCFail = mapper.Map<A, IEnumerable<C>>(instanceA); // Throw the following exception: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'
```

I thought this use case (class A to IEnumerable) should works, what did I missed ?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No transitivity I'm afraid, that's what the message is telling you and you''ll have to add the missing map.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment:

> No transitivity I'm afraid, that's what the message is telling you and you''ll have to add the missing map. –
> Lucian Bargaoan

Even though there are mappings from `A` to `IEnumerable<B>` and `B` to class `C`, it is not enough for **AutoMapper** to understand how should the "derived" mapping work. It needs to know the mapping explicitly:

```
cfg.CreateMap<A, IEnumerable<C>>()
    .ConvertUsing(a => a.listB.Select(b => mapper.Map<B, C>(b)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am going to to this with your suggestion :)